# How to port SWT to a new platform?

Tags: java, swt

Is there any documentation on what the interface between SWT and my native-platform calls should look like and how i can test it ?

this is the closest i could find, but not extremely useful.
http://book.javanb.com/swt-the-standard-widget-toolkit/fm01lev1sec5.html

Answer (score 3):

You would have better luck ask in swt mail list. 
Quoted from http://www.eclipse.org/swt/ :

> If you are modifying or porting SWT
>   and have questions, try the SWT
>   developer [mailing list](http://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/platform-swt-dev) ([archive](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/platform-swt-dev/)).